# How can I iterate through a TreeMap and use reflection to get a subclass name?

Tags: java, reflection, subclass, treemap

Suppose I had the following abstract class and two subclasses:

```
public abstract class Contact {
    private String name;

    public void showDetails() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

public class Personal extends Contact {
    private String relationship;

    // @override
    public void showDetails() {
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(relationship);
    }
}

public class Business extends Contact {
    private String company;

    // @override
    public void showDetails() {
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(company);
    }
}
```

Also suppose that I have a TreeMap containing integers as keys and either Business objects or Personal objects as values:

```
Map<Integer, Contact> masterList = new TreeMap<Integer, Contact>();

masterList.put(1, bContact1);
masterList.put(2, bContact2);
masterList.put(3, pContact1);
masterList.put(4, pContact2);
```

Is it possible to iterate through the TreeMap AND use reflection to see what subclass each object belongs to, in order to use the correct overriding method?

For example, key 1 is paired with bContact1, which is a Business object. I want to use the showDetails() method from the Business subclass for this particular value.

I can iterate through the map just fine, but I'm having trouble with the reflection part. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need reflection, you need polymorphism. Just call the method on the object, Java will do the rest to invoke the proper implementation.

```
Contact contactRef = masterList.get(2);
contactRef.showDetails(); // overriden method invoked if it exists, inherited otherwise
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a habit of over-complicating things.
Edit: Can I do this even though Contact is an abstract class?

Comment: @NojoRu Yes. You should read up on inheritance and polymorphism. This is one of their properties.